# C Structure holding a pointer to another structure how access member of that inner structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, structure

The structure looks like this

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION {
  HANDLE hProcess;
  HANDLE hThread;
  DWORD  dwProcessId;
  DWORD  dwThreadId;
} PROCESS_INFORMATION, *LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;


struct PLAYER
{
  /* 0x0/0 */ struct PROCESS_INFORMATION *ProcessInformation;
  /* 0x4/4 */ unsigned long dword4;
  /* 0x8/8 */ unsigned long dword8;
  /* 0xC/12 */ unsigned long dwordC;
  //... Lots of fields here
}
```

Here is the prototype for `TerminateProcess`

```
BOOL WINAPI TerminateProcess(
  _In_  HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_  UINT uExitCode
);
```

I tried all 3 of these below and failed.

```
unsigned int v102; //exit code.
struct PLAYER *player; // eax@9

TerminateProcess(player->ProcessInformation->hProcess, v102);
TerminateProcess(player->ProcessInformation.hProcess, v102);
TerminateProcess(*(player->ProcessInformation)->hProcess, v102);
```

The arrow `->` works for other members of the `PLAYER struct pointer` but if the member inside the `struct` PLAYER is a pointer to another struct then I get compiler problems.

All 3 above give me the compiler problems.

Maybe I had to use `*LPPROCESS_INFORMATION` inside the `struct PLAYER` or maybe I had to use `struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION *` because I really hate using `typedef`'s

(yeah I just started using C only a week ago I usually code in Java/C#/VB.NET so this is all new to me.)

**Edit: Seems I found the problem I was using a stupid `typedef` no wonder I had so much problems.. Those typedef's eliminate the use for a type which in this case is a `struct` so my structure was very screwed up..**

Fix was to replace

```
/* 0x0/0 */ struct PROCESS_INFORMATION *ProcessInformation;
```

with

```
/* 0x0/0 */ struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION *ProcessInformation;
```

Now I can use the beautifiul arrows non-stop

```
player->ProcessInformation->hProcess
```

Is this right?

Comment: the function prototype for TerminateProcess() would be helpful in coming up with an answer.  What are the type(s) of the parameter(s) of TerminateProcess()?  Is TerminateProcess() part of your code, or is it supplied by a library?

Comment: I posted it now, it's the one from `windows.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player->ProcessInformation->hProcess
```

is correct.   Good luck!